# How can i fix the deployement error 'starter.cmd "D:\home\site\d ..."' was aborted

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am having this error while deploying my nodejs code to azure app service through CD linked to my azure repos repository :

> "Command 'starter.cmd "D:\home\site\d ...' was aborted due to no
> output nor CPU activity for 60 seconds. You can increase the
> SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this
> is a WebJob) if needed.\r\nstarter.cmd
> "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd""

Any ideas ? Thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/veleek/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#changing-the-timeout-before-external-commands-are-killed

Answer (score 1):

Agree to the solution that is shared by Sneha

1. my first solution would be increasing the "SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT" to 600 in the app setting of the web app.
2. Alternatively, If expecting a CONTINUOUS webjob this isn't something that happens by default (Even though the webjob appears to run by the rules until timeout). This is something that has to be selected in the Visual Studio Publish properties as [detailed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs)

Once continuous is selected and the webjob is published, this error goes away

3. If you are using vnet integration you need to remove WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1 in application setting. The deployment will be successful. Without this setting, web app routes only RFC1918 traffic into the VNet.

This document covers more information about [integration with virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet)